# Why this if statment into a Spring MVC JSP page can't work?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I am pretty new in **Spring MVC** and **JSP** page and I have the following problem.

Into a controller class I add these 2 collections to my **model** object:

```
List<Integer> numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> numeroProgettiPnsdScuoleList = new ArrayList<>();
```

by these lines:

```
model.addAttribute("numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList", numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList);
model.addAttribute("numeroProgettiPnsdScuoleList", numeroProgettiPnsdScuoleList);
```

And it works fine. The problem is that now into my **JSP** page I have something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${listaScuoleDS}" var="scuola" varStatus="item">

    <c:if test="${numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList[item.index] == 0}">
        <p>Nessun progetto WIFI associato alla scuola</p>
    </c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

So, as you can see, into the **forEach** cycle I have to perform an **if** test that check if the value of the **numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList** collection related to the current item in the iteration (**item.index**) is equal to 0. In this case show a text.

But in this way don't work (the 



 tag is not shown).

Why? What am I missing? How can i fix this issue?

Comment: try printing the length of `listaScuoleDS`, bu using `${fn:length(listaScuoleDS)}`, so that you will know that loop is executing. For this, you will have to add `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>` in JSP. Also try printing the element value itself inside loop, like `${numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList[item.index]` to see what is the actual value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the var name in IF condition..Because you are using JSTL tag to get the value.

```
<c:set var ="numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList" value=${numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList}">
    <c:forEach items="${listaScuoleDS}" var="scuola" varStatus="item">

        <c:if test="${scuola[item.index] == 0}">
            <p>Nessun progetto WIFI associato alla scuola</p>
        </c:if>

    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: No...I am not understanding you...I have to check the item.index element (this is an id) into the numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList list that was putted into the model object by the controller

Comment: Then first you have put your object into var like `<c:set var ="numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList" value=${numeroProgettiWifiScuoleList}">` then only you can use.